# What is the difference between PM_DATA_ALL* and PM_DATA* events on Power8?

Tags: powerpc, perf, oprofile, papi

During evaluation of memory performance of Power8 processor using `perf` I ended up with problem of understanding difference between events `PM_DATA_ALL_*` and `PM_DATA_*`. Most of the counters exists in both version, but the description in [oprofile documentation](http://sourceforge.net/p/oprofile/oprofile/ci/master/tree/events/ppc64/architected_events_v1/events) and in `papi_native_avail` are the same, for example:

> **PM_DATA_FROM_LMEM**
>
> The processor's data cache was reloaded from the local chip's Memory due to either only demand loads or demand loads plus prefetches if MMCR1[16] is 1.

I though I will figure out the difference by measuring some data. If I provide task large enough, I can observe expected difference that `*_ALL` versions have higher values. I understand the concept of multiplexing counters in the measure using `perf`.

So what is actually the all in these events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After few more hours of searching, I found another [source directly from IBM](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFK5S_2.2.0/com.ibm.cluster.pedev.v2r2.pedev100.doc/bl7ug_power8metrics.htm) describing the events as:

> **PM_DATA_ALL_FROM_LMEM**
>
> The processor's data cache was reloaded from the local chip's Memory due to either demand loads *or data prefetch*

and

> **PM_DATA_FROM_LMEM**
>
> The processor's data cache was reloaded from the local chip's Memory due to a demand load

So the difference makes **prefetch** load, which is not included in the second version.

The PAPI and perf tools just include wrong description. These events were [contributed](http://sourceforge.net/p/oprofile/oprofile/ci/cfecfbfa3e5c76ab544f64946af38a7f2efec9a3/log/?path=/events/ppc64/power8/events) directly to `oprofile` by IBM but probably with some mistakes/inaccuracies. As I browse through the [PAPI/libpfm source](https://sourceforge.net/p/perfmon2/libpfm4/ci/master/tree/lib/events/power8_events.h), I see that the correct description is in `.pme_short_desc` field, but the `.pme_long_desc` fields are both the same. And `papi_native_avail` reports only the long one:
[image: Thanks ... Very fu**ing useful!]

Thanks for patience. Summing the stuff like this helped me a lot and I hope it will help somebody struggling with similar issues.